# When to favor rejection sampling over importance sampling

Tags: simulation

I asked a question about importance vs rejection sampling: [Importance sampling vs acceptance-rejection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/540382/importance-sampling-vs-acceptance-rejection) and why one would use rejection sampling when importance sampling should produce a lower variance because it doesn't outright drop any samples. A question linked was this one: [What is the difference between Metropolis-Hastings, Gibbs, Importance, and Rejection sampling?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/185631/what-is-the-difference-between-metropolis-hastings-gibbs-importance-and-rejec) which asks about a much broader range of simulation techniques and the only distinction between importance and rejection sampling I could discern (and was also pointed out) from the answer was that rejection sampling produces an i.i.d sample while importance sampling does not.

This is good to know, but I still am not able to use this information on my original question which was - what would be an actual scenario where rejection sampling would be better applicable than importance sampling. In almost all instances of simulation, I feel we end up finding some kind of average anyway. In fact, this statement was made by the professor who taught a course on simulation I took (except, he didn't say "almost").

Answer (score 4):

It is incorrect to see simulation as reduced to Monte Carlo integration. There are [many other usages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_simulation#Computer_simulation_in_practical_contexts) of computer simulation. In particular, dynamical systems as in [statistical mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_physics) that are driven by differential equations are rarely allowing for an analytical solution and require simulation to describe their equilibrium distribution.

A very specific instance when importance sampling cannot be used is the case of the [pseudo-marginal Metropolis–Hastings algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-marginal_Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm): this is a Metropolis algorithm where the target density $\pi(\theta)$ is replaced with an unbiased estimator (of said density), $\hat\pi(\theta,\xi)$, with $\xi\sim \varpi(\xi|\theta)$. Ẁhile resorting to an accept-reject algorithm to produce a simulation from $\varpi(\xi|\theta)$ is acceptable, using instead a self-normalised importance sampling estimate of $\pi(\theta)$ is not valid because it breaks the unbiasedness requirement. (A simple experiment shows that the resulting Markov chain does not converge to the intended target $\pi(\theta)$.)

**Reminder:** the (usual) variance improvement brought by unbiased importance sampling over accept-reject simulation only applies when the variance exists.

Note also that, given an accept-reject output, producing an iid sample $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ from an overall sample (containing rejected values) $y_1,\ldots,y_N$, and auxiliary uniforms, $u_1,\ldots,u_N$, a [variance improvement over the sample average](https://ecommons.cornell.edu/bitstream/handle/1813/31839/BU-1252-M.pdf;sequence=1)
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n h(x_i)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^N h(y_j)\mathbb I_{u_j<\varrho(y_j)}$$
[where $\varrho(y_j)$ is the acceptance ratio] can be found by integrating out the $u_j$'s, conditional on the $y_j$'s and $n$ being accepted. The domination follows from [a Rao-Blackwell argument](https://xianblog.files.wordpress.com/2021/07/nwvse-1.png).